# Export Compliance for an app that uses the Safari component in the Mac App Store

Tags: macos, encryption, mac-app-store

I'm submitting an app to the Mac App Store and this app uses the Safari component to display web pages. I'm being asked this question:

> Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography? (Select Yes even if your app is only utilizing the encryption available in iOS or OS X.)

Should I answer yes due to the possibility of HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a resounding yes. I talked to Apple representatives and they [confirmed the need of an ERN if you just use standard SSL in the form of HTTPS](https://carouselapps.com/2015/12/09/mac-ios-applications-breaking-rules-removed/). There are many blog posts and forums out there saying that you can just say no and everything is fine, but I don't believe they are following the rules, they are just not being caught at an audit might find their applications pulled from the app store. For those arriving here hopping the answer was no, I'm sorry.

But there's hope. I actually got an ERN and I described all the nitty gritty details so you can do it too with the minimum of pain in my blog post: [How to legally submit an app to Apple’s App Store when it uses encryption (or how to obtain an ERN)](https://carouselapps.com/2015/12/15/legally-submit-app-apples-app-store-uses-encryption-obtain-ern/)

Comment: I asked in person at WWDC 2016 and was told you can answer  no to that question. Part of the reason is that you can't know is a http site will redirect to an https site.

Comment: @zaph What if you hit an API using HTTPS? Seems like you would know then.

Comment: @AaronBrager The rational was that  since you might unknowingly hit an HTTPS site and that was OK hitting a known HTTPS site is essentially the same. I was not really happy with the answer but that is what I got. I did request a clarification and the Apple employee stood with the answer. This was a security person I was directed to for my specific question in a security "Lab". FWIW I previously held the belief that the answer should be yes.

Comment: Yeah, just seems like if your app includes a browser that supports HTTPS at all, then the answer to "Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography?" is yes

Comment: @AaronBrager Using HTTPS is not directly using encryption, there are no explicit calls to an encryption function in the code, the code never handles any encrypted data, it is the Apple transport layer that is involved in encryption. There are other examples of encryption the app may use transparently such as saving data in the Keychain, writing data to disk is using encryption since there is full disk encryption, are these too the app using encryption? I posit that these uses do not qualify as an app using encryption.

Comment: @zaph That would be my hope, but *even if your app is only utilizing the encryption available in iOS* sounds (to me — it's obviously subjective) like it would include the keychain. Maybe I'll burn a TSI and see if I can get some more clarity in writing